# What error numbers can be returned by SqlCommand.ExecuteXXX() when timeout occures

Tags: sql-server

I need to handle timeouts when executing SQL statements in C#.  For handling deadlocks I would look for error code 1205.  I am wondering what error codes I need to look at when looking for timeouts.  Querying the messages table of SQLServer for error messages containing the term 'timeout' I get beck somewhat around 30 records.  Which of those are relevant for SqlCommand.ExecuteXXX()?

Comment: Here is a very helpfull link I found:  <http://blog.colinmackay.net/archive/2007/06/23/65.aspx>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timeout is -2: it doesn't come from SQL Server itself but your client drivers.